# Get mongo server version >= 3.6

Tags: apt, 18.04, mongodb

On Ubuntu 18.04 I run this:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
mongo
```

And get this in mongo shell greeting output:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
WARNING: No implicit session: Logical Sessions are only supported on     server versions 3.6 and greater.
Implicit session: dummy session
MongoDB server version: 3.4.16
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
```

But I want to get server version >= 3.6. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you have MongoDB 3.4 installed and running before upgrading to 4.0? If so, did you stop the `mongod` service before upgrading? Note: if you are upgrading, the [supported upgrade path](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/) is via successive major releases (3.4 => 3.6, 3.6 => 4.0). Skipping one or more major releases may require some extra admin work depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongodb source list file to install =>3.6 mongodb version.

Create the source list file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list`.

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

Update package database.

```
sudo apt update
```

You can define version number while installation. 
For example,Here I have pinned 4.0.5 version.

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.0.5 mongodb-org-server=4.0.5 mongodb-org-shell=4.0.5 mongodb-org-mongos=4.0.5 mongodb-org-tools=4.0.5
```

Comment: I have already done it, from this doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
It doesnt help me

Comment: For me it installs latest packages 4.0.5 version. You can also pin specific version.
Can you provide more info with output ?

Comment: It installs shell version 4.0.5, but server version 3.4.16

Comment: Then you can upgrade it. 
sudo apt upgrade mongodb-org-server=4.0.5